# Julia DataFrame: data type definition as array is unacceptable?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

it is uncertain but array type cannot define as DF column type?

```
    ex.
       a = Array{String,1}
       b = String[]
       c = Float64[]
    
       df= DataFrame(:a => a, :b => b, :c => c)
    
        Row │ a                      b           c 
    │       │ Any                 String     Float64       
    │  ─────┼───────────────────────────────────────
    │   1   │ ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]  something    2.0 
    │   ⋮  │        ⋮              ⋮           ⋮
```

As you can see, the data type of "a" column is "Any", despite defined Array.
Indeed a column contains data alike ["aaa","bbb","ccc"].

Because of defininig "Any", "a" data is to be vector{any} when it is picked up from it.
You may say convert "a" to array type after picking up from, though looks like unwise. :-p

I would wana handle "a" array data as a array data after picking up from the df as well.

The df definition is not correct?

Any advices appreciate.Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code. `a` should be an instance of the vector of the type you want not just the type itself (which would be treated as a value). So, with some minor other tweaks, means that what you need to write is:

```
julia> a = Vector{String}[]
Vector{String}[]

julia> b = String[]
String[]

julia> c = Float64[]
Float64[]

julia> df= DataFrame(; a, b, c)
0×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b       c
     │ Array…  String  Float64
─────┴─────────────────────────

julia> eltype.(eachcol(df))
3-element Vector{DataType}:
 Vector{String} (alias for Array{String, 1})
 String
 Float64
```

Comment: Oh oh oh, my definition was wrong, was not it? Thank you Dr.Kaminski as always, YOUR suggestions alwasy help me a lot.